# JPQL Left Join - how to set up entity relationship in entity classes

Tags: java, sql, jpql

Two tables:

```
TABLE_1:
REC_ID
1
2
3
4

TABLE_2:
REC_ID REC_VAL
2      A
3      B
```

Entity classes (basic structure):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_1")
public class Entity1 {
    @Id
    @Column(name="REC_ID")
    private String recId;

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_2")
public class Entity2 {
    @Id
    @Column(name="REC_ID")
    private String recId;

    @Column(name="REC_VAL")
    private String recVal;

    //getters and setters
}
```

SQL Query and result:

```
SELECT T1.REC_ID, T2.REC_VAL FROM TABLE_1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T1.REC_ID = T2.RED_ID

Result:
REC_ID REC_VAL
1      null
2      A
3      B
4      null
```

JPQL Query:

```
SELECT e1.recId, e2.recVal FROM Entity1 e1 LEFT JOIN e1.<an Entity2 field in Entity1*>
```

* I know I don't have it in the given structure above, but I want to know how to do it right. And how do I choose from @ManyToOne, @OneToOne, etc.

**How do I modify the Entity classes and the JPQL query to achieve the same result as the SQL query?** I've been trying various things, nothing works. It wouldn't allow me to create two fields with the same column name, or to define the String as the @JoinColumn. I almost got it working, but the generated SQL query contains a reference to REC_ID_REC_ID column in TABLE_2 which doesn't exist. And after Googling so much, I can't find a proper guide for this (*ignoring that JPQL does not support in-line join conditions!*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a OneToOne association between the entities. And the association, on the owning side, must be annotated with `@MapsId`. Here's an example taken from the Hibernate documentation, which maps to your use-case:

```
@Entity
public class Body {
    @Id
    public Long getId() { return id; }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId
    public Heart getHeart() {
        return heart;
    }
    ...
}   

@Entity
public class Heart {
    @Id
    public Long getId() { ...}
}
```

Once you have that, you can use a query such as

```
select b.foo, h.bar from Body b left join b.heart h where ...
```

Comment: Oh alright. I didn't know about @MapsId. Will try it tomorrow and let u know. Can you however rewrite the entity classes I have in my question? It will be easier to understand :) thanks!

Comment: No. You should be able to figure that out by yourself.

Comment: I hope I can :/ it has been annoying me for 2 days

Comment: I don't have MapsId in the version of persistence API I'm using (1.0). It's a large system, so upgrading can break things. Also, what if the columns I want to join on are not primary keys? Then how do I approach this?

Comment: No idea for JPA 1.0. Joining on non-PK, although a bad idea, can be done as for any other association: by providing the referenced column name(s) in the annotation.